# android - access camera force close api 29

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

I'm trying to capture an image from camera and store the image in the memory , this is my code that gets into an error
it works fine on android pre 9 but on android 9+ it crashes

```
fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getCacheImagePath(fileName));
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        }
private Uri getCacheImagePath(String fileName) {
    File path = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "camera");
    if (!path.exists()) path.mkdirs();
    File image = new File(path, fileName);
    return getUriForFile(ImagePickerActivity.this, getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", image);
}
```

i've granted both camera and write external permissions, i've defined these permissions in manifest too

the stack doesnt return any errors (weird) , this is the exact line that it doesn't go further

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getCacheImagePath(fileName));
```

what should I do  ?

Comment: The exact line? But what causes the problem? The putExtra or getting the catche image path? Separate those statemants to find out.

Comment: `getUriForFile` That is a function of which class?